# PHP dynamic SQL execute parameters

Tags: php, sql, arrays

So I'm building an `SQL statement` dynamically for a small search form.

I have a series of `IFs` where I check what filters the user decided to use when searching.

If the user decided to use the Operating System filter (a dropdown box he chooses from), I want to add

```
$statement->execute(array(
        ':osFilter'=>$osFilter,
        ));
```

If the user selected a second filter, I need another element to be added to this `array` so that it looks like this:

```
$statement->execute(array(
        ':osFilter'=>$osFilter,
        ':versionFilter'=>$versionFilter,
        ));
```

I thought the way to do this is to create an array as I go to through the IFs and then just pass it in execute() but it didn't work.

That's the code  I tried:

```
 $filtersArray = array();

if (some condition) {
            array_push($filtersArray, array(
':osFilter' => $osFilter,
));
               }
```

I do the same for the rest of the IF statements and then pass the constructed array like this:

```
    $statement->execute($filtersArray);
```

I get this error: **"Array to string conversion..."**

Any ideas, what's the proper way of doing things here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create multi dimensional array. Just use `$filtersArray[':osFilter'] = $osFilter;`.

Comment: I found the answer a few minutes ago but since you posted it first, I will accept. What a simple mistake I made but I never thought using push() will not work. Thanks anyway!